# I am trying to create a sudoku solver, however I am stuck and cannot find the mistake

Tags: python, sudoku

So I am trying to create a sudoku solver, however, I am stuck.

When the number reaches 10, it should go back one square and try again. However, when it reaches number 10, it suddenly goes to a negative row.

I have tried rewriting my code to see if anything would change due to a semantic error, however, it still doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out.

***Edited question / problem:***

When it reaches number 10, it should change the variable direct to "back". Then when new_square is called, it should go one position back. But then for some reason, it infinitely goes back, until the row goes to the negative (position was 1 7, but it almost like recursion it goes back one column, until it goes into the minus row).

The code:

```
sudoku = [
#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    [8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5],  # 0
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 6],  # 1
    [0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0],  # 2
    [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],  # 3
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 4
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8],  # 5
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8, 0],  # 6
    [4, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  # 7
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4]   # 8
]

original = tuple(sudoku)

row = 0
column = 0
direct = "forw"
number = 0
steps = 0

game_change = True


def start():
    global row, column, number, direct, steps
    steps += 1

    if not ((sudoku[row][column] == original[row][column]) and sudoku[row][column] != 0):
        direct = "forw"
        if number == 0:
            number = 1

        if number != 10:
            direct = "forw"
            rowc = row_check()
            colc = column_check()
            boxc = box_check()

            if rowc and colc and boxc:
                sudoku[row][column] = number

                new_square()
                number = sudoku[row][column]
            else:
                number += 1
        else:
            direct = "back"
            new_square()
            number = sudoku[row][column] + 1
            return
    else:
        new_square()
        number = sudoku[row][column] + 1
        return


def row_check():
    global row, number
    if number not in sudoku[row]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def column_check():
    global column, number
    new_col = []
    for i in range(9):
        new_col.append(sudoku[i][column])
    if number not in new_col:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def box_check():
    global row, column, number
    srow = 0
    scol = 0
    if row in [0, 1, 2]:
        srow = 0
    elif row in [3, 4, 5]:
        srow = 3
    elif row in [6, 7, 8]:
        srow = 6

    if column in [0, 1, 2]:
        scol = 0
    elif column in [3, 4, 5]:
        scol = 3
    elif column in [6, 7, 8]:
        scol = 6

    new_box = []
    for i in range(srow, (srow + 3)):
        for j in range(scol, (scol + 3)):
            new_box.append(sudoku[i][j])
    if number not in new_box:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def new_square():
    global row, column, direct
    if direct == "forw":
        if column == 8:
            column = 0
            row += 1
        else:
            column += 1
    else:
        if column != 0:
            column -= 1
        else:
            column = 8
            row -= 1



while game_change:
    start()
    if steps % 1000 == 0:


print("It is done")
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: don't use `global` pass the variables as parameters. If you don't want to do that, then it all should be a class and the functions should be it's methods.

Comment: If you could find a minimal example (Minimal code that works differently that you expect), people would read it. Nobody will read 127 lines of code.

Comment: "When the number reaches 10, it should go back one square and try again" Where should this happen? In which function? on what line? Ideally, put a comment there`# the counter should restart to 0 here`

Comment: Also, when I run your code I get SyntaxError at the end. You are missing a code block after `if steps % 1000 == 0:`.

Comment: I will be very glad to help you once you fix all three of these issues. (You don't have to remove the `globals` for me to help you.)

Answer (score 2):

## Answering the question

### deepcopy

First up I noticed `original = tuple(sudoku)`. This won't do. You are creating [shallow copy but you want deepcopy](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy). In short: if you edit a row in `sudoku`, the corresponding row in `original` will change as well.
To prevent that, use deep copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
original = deepcopy(sudoku)
```

### What now?

I tried to debug your code further. Mainly I added a few prints and a nice `print_with_cursor` function. I wasn't very successful, there is my code for future reference.

```
from copy import deepcopy

sudoku = [
#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    [8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5],  # 0
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 6],  # 1
    [0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0],  # 2
    [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],  # 3
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 4
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8],  # 5
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8, 0],  # 6
    [4, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  # 7
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4]   # 8
]

original = deepcopy(sudoku)

row = 0
column = 0
direct = "forw"
number = 0
steps = 0

game_change = True


def start(row, column, number, direct, steps):
    steps += 1

    print(f"row {row}, column {column}, number {number}", end="")
    if not ((sudoku[row][column] == original[row][column]) and sudoku[row][column] != 0):
        direct = "forw"
        if number == 0:
            number = 1

        if number != 10:
            direct = "forw"
            rowc = number not in sudoku[row]
            colc = column_check(column, number)
            boxc = box_check(row, column, number)

            if rowc and colc and boxc:
                sudoku[row][column] = number

                print(" set")
                print_with_cursor(sudoku, row, column)
                row, column = new_square(row, column, direct)
                number = sudoku[row][column]
            else:
                if sudoku[row][column] != 0:
                    sudoku[row][column] = 0  # added
                    print(" reset")
                    print_with_cursor(sudoku, row, column)
                number += 1
        else:
            direct = "back"
            print(" unfillable")
            print_with_cursor(sudoku, row, column)
            row, column = new_square(row, column, direct)
            number = sudoku[row][column] + 1
    else:
        row, column = new_square(row, column, direct)
        number = sudoku[row][column] + 1
    print()
    return row, column, number, direct, steps


def print_with_cursor(sudoku, row, column):
    print(f'{" "*column}v')
    for irow, prow in enumerate(sudoku):
        print(f'{"".join(str(p) for p in prow)}{"<" if irow == row else ""}')

def column_check(column, number):
    new_col = []
    for i in range(9):
        new_col.append(sudoku[i][column])
    return number not in new_col


def box_check(row, column, number):
    if row in [0, 1, 2]:
        srow = 0
    elif row in [3, 4, 5]:
        srow = 3
    elif row in [6, 7, 8]:
        srow = 6

    if column in [0, 1, 2]:
        scol = 0
    elif column in [3, 4, 5]:
        scol = 3
    elif column in [6, 7, 8]:
        scol = 6

    new_box = []
    for i in range(srow, (srow + 3)):
        for j in range(scol, (scol + 3)):
            new_box.append(sudoku[i][j])
    return number not in new_box


def new_square(row, column, direct):
    if direct == "forw":
        if column == 8:
            column = 0
            row += 1
        else:
            column += 1
    else:
        if column != 0:
            column -= 1
        else:
            column = 8
            row -= 1
    return row, column



while game_change:
    row, column, number, direct, steps = start(row, column, number, direct, steps)


print("It is done")
```

The debug starts like this:

```
row 0, column 0, number 0
row 0, column 1, number 1
row 0, column 1, number 2
row 0, column 1, number 3 set
 v
831000045<
000000706
056000800
090700100
000080000
000200538
000040080
427000010
000090004

row 0, column 2, number 1
row 0, column 3, number 1
row 0, column 3, number 2
row 0, column 3, number 3
row 0, column 3, number 4
row 0, column 3, number 5
row 0, column 3, number 6 set
   v
831600045<
000000706
056000800
090700100
000080000
000200538
000040080
427000010
000090004
...
```

## Code improvements

Let's upgrade your code! We can answer your question later, when the code is simpler to understand.

### First up: fix SyntaxError

You are missing a code block after `if steps % 1000 == 0:`

```
while game_change:
    start()
    if steps % 1000 == 0:


print("It is done")
```

### Secondly: get rid off `global`.

Then your code will be much more readable!

instead of

```
def new_square():
    global row, column, direct
    # do something
```

use

```
def new_square(row, column, direct):
    # do something
    return row, column
```

Then to call it, instead of

```
new_square()
```

use

```
row, column = new_square(row, column, direct)
```

Notice that now you get a much better idea of what the function does simply by looking at the call in the code.

Also: I am not a big fan of abbreviation `direct` of `direction`. I would rather see the whole word.

### Bonus 1, inline function row_check:

```
def row_check():
    global row, number
    if number not in sudoku[row]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can be simplified down to

```
def row_check():
    global row, number
    return number not in sudoku[row]
```

Note: use this simplification in all the `X_check` functions!

Now, this can be inlined, it is even used only in one place:

replace `rowc = row_check()`

by `rowc = number not in sudoku[row]`

### Bonus 2, simplify `X_check`:

`X_check`'s end with creating a list, checking if a number is in that list. Instead, we can iterate over what we are creating the list from and check whether the number is there. Maybe it is better understood with the solution:

create list of numbers in a sudoku box, then check if `number` is there

```
def box_check(row, column, number):
    # setting srow & scol to be one of 0, 3, 6

    new_box = []
    for i in range(srow, (srow + 3)):
        for j in range(scol, (scol + 3)):
            new_box.append(sudoku[i][j])
    return number not in new_box
```

check if `number` is in a sudoku box

```
def box_check(row, column, number):
    # setting srow & scol to be one of 0, 3, 6

    for i in range(srow, (srow + 3)):
        for j in range(scol, (scol + 3)):
            if number == sudoku[i][j]:
                return False
    return True
```

These two are the same, but the second doesn't use extra list, is simpler to understand. (And is more optimised, but that's not that important).

#### Do the same for `column_check`

Replace

```
def column_check(column, number):
    new_col = []
    for i in range(9):
        new_col.append(sudoku[i][column])
    return number not in new_col
```

with

```
def column_check(column, number):
    for i in range(9):
        if number == sudoku[i][column]:
            return False
    return True
```

We can go further there, replacing the `range(9)` by what is actually happening, we simplify it further to get:

```
def column_check(column, number):
    for row in sudoku:
        if number == row[column]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: The syntax error happened because before posting I deleted all both the print statements so that it would be a bit less code.
What I hope to achieve is that if one number fits, it goes to the next square. So lets say, the number 3 can go into the board, it will move onto the next square and try every number until it can't anymore.
An example would be position 1 7 (row 2, column 8). There, if you run the code, no number between 1-9 fits. So ideally it should go back one square and try a new number, which would be adding 1 to the number. And that is where my problem occurs.

Comment: When it reaches number 10, it should change the variable direct to "back". Then when new_square is called, it should go one position back. But then for some reason, it infinitely goes back, until the row goes to the negative (position was 1 7, but it almost like recursion it goes back one column, until it goes into the minus row).

Comment: You shouldn't reply to my answer with this. You should fix your question (edit it). Then you can notify me by simply saying "Fixed my question".